# Grid layout "last" class to every third item

Tags: templates, posts

Seems like a trivial problem but I can't get it to work. I need to add `class="last"` to every third post.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
     $count = 0;
     $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=-18,-7&showposts=9');
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <article class="<?php if ($count % 3 == 0) { echo "last "; }" ?>> </article>

    <?php 
          $count++;
          endwhile; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the missing '?>' after the if statement just a typo or is that copy/pasted from your code?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Just checking :)

Comment: You should increment the counter at the start of the loop, or alternatively set the initial value to 1, else your counter has a starting value of zero for the first result. (edit: should have scrolled down, my bad).

Comment: Do you have the final code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to start the `$count` variable from 1 and not zero. You'll get the opposite effect otherwise because 0 modulo 3 is 0. The first item of every 3 will be getting the class name.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. ONLY the third item in each rows has to have the class="last"

Comment: Yeah. Starting the count from 1 does what you want in my own tests. Can you explain what effect you're actually seeing with the counter starting on 1 so I can help?

Comment: @Eeyore: If you want *only* the third item, you should not use `($count % 3 == 0)` but `($count == 3)`. If you want items # 3, 6, 9, ... to have this class you use the modulo (`%`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need mod operator here for, it is usual for keeping track of even/odd values. You simply need every third.

```
$i = 0;

//while stuff
    $i++;
    if( 3 == $i ) {
        $i = 0;
        echo 'last';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

start the count from 1

```
post number count value %value
1                1          1
2                2          2
3                3          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for a way to do the same for use with the WordPress starter theme, 'Bones'. It also has a 'first' class. I post that here in case it helps anybody else.

```
<div class="wrap clearfix">
<?php 
$count = 1;
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <article class="
        <?php 
            //echo $count.' ';
            if ($count % 3 == 0) {echo 'last ';} 
            if ($count == 1 || $count % 3 == 1) {echo 'first ';}
        ?>fourcol"> 
        <h4><?php echo $cat->cat_name ?></h4>
        <div class="desc"><?php echo $cat->category_description ?></div>
    </article>
<?php $count++;} ?>
```